# How to sum or count groups of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group several group of columns to count or sum the rows in a pandas dataframe

I've checked many questions already and the most similar I found is this one > [Groupby sum and count on multiple columns in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768650/groupby-sum-and-count-on-multiple-columns-in-python), but, by what I understand I have to do many steps to reach my goal. and was also looking at this [link](https://dfrieds.com/data-analysis/pivot-table-python-pandas)

As an example, I have the dataframe below:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 7)), columns=["grey2","red1","blue1","red2","red3","blue2","grey1"])

     grey2   red1 blue1 red2 red3 blue2 grey1
0       4      3    0      2    4   0   2
1       4      2    0      4    0   3   1
2       1      1    3      1    1   3   1
3       4      4    1      4    1   1   1
4       3      4    1      0    3   3   1
```

I want to group here, all the columns by colour, for example, and what I would expect is:

If I sum the numbers,

```
blue  15
grey  22
red   34
```

If I count ( x > 0 ) then I will get,

```
  blue  7
  grey  10
  red   13
```

this is what I have achieved so far, so now i will have to sum and then create a dataframe with the results, but if I have 100 groups,this would be very time consuming.

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=df.index, values=["red1","red2","red3"], aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
   red1  red2   red3
0    3     2    4
1    2     4    0
2    1     1    1
3    4     4    1
4    4     0    3
ALL  14   11    9

pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=df.index, values=["red1","red2","red3"], aggfunc='count', margins=True)
```

But here is also counting the zeros:

```
     red1 red2  red3
   0    1   1   1
   1    1   1   1
   2    1   1   1
   3    1   1   1
   4    1   1   1
  All   5   5   5
```

Not sure how to alter the function to get my results, and I've already spend hours, hopefully you can help.

NOTE:
I only use colours in this example to simplify the case, but I could have around many columns and they are called col001 till col300, etc...
So, the groups could be:

```
blue = col131, col254, col005
red =  col023, col190, col053
```

and so on.....

Comment: `df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace('\d+', ''),axis=1).sum().sum()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
data= pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['grey','red','blue'], 
                i='index',
                j='group',
                sep=''
               )
```

Output:

```
# data
             grey  red  blue
index group                 
0     1       2.0    3   0.0
      2       4.0    2   0.0
      3       NaN    4   NaN
1     1       1.0    2   0.0
      2       4.0    4   3.0
      3       NaN    0   NaN
2     1       1.0    1   3.0
      2       1.0    1   3.0
      3       NaN    1   NaN
3     1       1.0    4   1.0
      2       4.0    4   1.0
      3       NaN    1   NaN
4     1       1.0    4   1.0
      2       3.0    0   3.0
      3       NaN    3   NaN
```

And:

```
data.sum()
# grey    22.0
# red     34.0
# blue    15.0
# dtype: float64

data.gt(0).sum()
# grey    10
# red     13
# blue     7
# dtype: int64
```

---

**Update** `wide_to_long` is just a convenient shortcut for `merge` and `rename`. So if you have a dictionary `{cat:[col_list]}`, you could resolve to that:

```
groups = {'blue' : ['col131', 'col254', 'col005'],
          'red' : ['col023', 'col190', 'col053']}

# create the inverse dictionary for mapping
inv_group = {v:k for k,v in groups.items()}

data = df.melt()

# map the original columns to group
data['group'] = data['variable'].map(inv_group)

# from now on, it's similar to other answers
# sum
data.groupby('group')['value'].sum()

# count
data['value'].gt(0).groupby(data['group']).sum()
```

Comment: thank you I have never heard of this function, I've just used colours to name the columns, but what if the columns are called with random names, can i use a dictionary in the stubnames?

Answer (score 1):

The complication here is that you want to collapse both by rows **and** columns, which is generally difficult to do at the same time. We can `melt` to go from your wide format to a longer format, which then reduces the problem to a single `groupby`

```
# Get rid of the numbers + reshape
df.columns = pd.Index(df.columns.str.rstrip('0123456789'), name='color')
df = df.melt()

df.groupby('color').sum()
#       value
#color       
#blue      15
#grey      22
#red       34

df.value.gt(0).groupby(df.color).sum()
#color
#blue     7.0
#grey    10.0
#red     13.0
#Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

With names that are less simple to group, we'd need to have the mapping somewhere, the steps are very similar:

```
# Unnecessary in this case, but more general
d = {'grey1': 'color_1', 'grey2': 'color_1', 
     'red1': 'color_2', 'red2': 'color_2', 'red3': 'color_2',
     'blue1': 'color_3', 'blue2': 'color_3'}

df.columns = pd.Index(df.columns.map(d), name='color')
df = df.melt()
df.groupby('color').sum()

#         value
#color         
#color_1     22
#color_2     34
#color_3     15
```

Comment: wow, that looks now pretty simple because I've just used colours to name the columns, but what if the columns are called with random names, and maybe I could prepare a dictionary with how they need to be grouped. For example: 
blue = col001, col134, col567
red = col876, col324, col9876

Comment: @VMEscoli The above would still group those three since `rstrip` will strip all of the numbers to the right, So those three would all become `'col'`. However if you instead needed to do some grouping like `col001, col134, col56` and then `col002, col007, col131` then clearly my option wont work. In that case you'd prepare the dictionary `d ={'col001': 'label1', 'col134': 'label1', ...}` and just replace the first step with `= ... df.columns.map(d) ...` If there's truly no simple pattern to the groupings, then you're going to have to write out the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace('\d+', ''),axis=1).sum().sum()
```

**Output:**

```
blue    15
grey    22
red     34
dtype: int64
```

---

**this works regardless of the number of digits contained in the name of the columns:**

```
df=df.add_suffix('22')
print(df)

   grey22222  red12222  blue12222  red22222  red32222  blue22222  grey12222
0          4         3          0         2         4          0          2
1          4         2          0         4         0          3          1
2          1         1          3         1         1          3          1
3          4         4          1         4         1          1          1
4          3         4          1         0         3          3          1

df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace('\d+', ''),axis=1).sum().sum()
blue    15
grey    22
red     34
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this for the general case:

```
colors = {'blue':['blue1','blue2'], 'red':['red1','red2','red3'], 'grey':['grey1','grey2']}
orig_columns = df.columns
df.columns = [key for col in df.columns for key in colors.keys() if col in colors[key]]
print(df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum().sum())
df.columns = orig_columns
```